# Logical equivalence and equality

Tags: equality

Let be $F=(A\land B)$ and $G=\neg(\neg A \lor \neg B)$. Which of the following statements are correct

$F=G, F\equiv G, \neg F=\neg G, \neg F\equiv\neg G$?

Is there a difference?

Comment: Hello! We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Did you try writing out a truth table? Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Equality* is a syntactic notion, *equivalence* is a semantic notion. Two expressions are *equal* if they are the same expression — in other words, an expression is only equal to itself. Two logical expressions are *equivalent* if they have the same truth value in every interpretation.

Two equal expressions are always equivalent, but the converse doesn't hold. For example, $A \equiv \lnot\lnot A$ but $A \neq \lnot\lnot A$.

Comment: Thank you for firstly for your answer! So, the right statements would be $\neg F\equiv \neg G$ and $F\equiv G$. I've proved these with a truth table.

Comment: These identities are known as the de Morgan laws, and they also hold when switching AND and OR.

Comment: What could be said similarly about <-> and <=> ? I guess <=> is semantic, but is it synonymous of the triple bar equal sign? Is <-> syntactic or semantic?

Comment: The symbols $\leftrightarrow$ and $\Leftrightarrow$ don't have any standard interpretation. You'll have to explain what these mean to you.

Comment: "Two expressions are equal if they are the same expression — in other words, an expression is only equal to itself." Perhaps you have something specific in mind when you say this, but its obviously not true outside of boolean formulas. Even within boolean formulas, equivalence satisfies all the 4 axioms of equality (reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity, and congruence) so ought to be treated as if it were equality over booleans